# Swift 4 core data sync with server (non-JSON data type)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift4

How can I sync my server data (an array of dictionary) to my core data in scenarios below  more efficiently?

1. update item in core data if item's attribute is changed in server
2. add item if not found in core data
3. finally, delete items in core data which not exist in server

My idea is as below but wonder if there is other more proper way or 3rd party library available to update my core data?

```
for coreItem in coreData {
    coreItem.isSynced = false
    for serverItem in serverData {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%s == %s", coreItem.ID , serverItem.ID )
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        var error: NSError?
        let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [item]
        if let results = fetchedResults {
           coreItem.isSynced = true
           if (results.count > 0) {
              //TODO --> item exists in core data. proceed to update all attributes for this item.
           }
           else {
                //TODO --> item does not exist in core data. proceed to add item to core data.
           }
        }
    }
    if (!coreItem.isSynced) {
        //TODO --> item is not found in server. proceed to delete data.
    }
}
```